# SQL: Extract from messy JSON nested field with backslashes

Tags: sql, json, hive, special-characters

I have a table that has some rows with normal JSON and some with escaped values in the JSON field (backslashes)

| id | obj |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"is_from_shopping_bag":true,"products":[{"price":{"amount":"18.00","currency":"USD","offset":100,"amount_with_offset":"1800"},"product_id":"1234","quantity":1}],"source":"cart"} |  |  |
| 2 | {"is_from_shopping_bag":"","products":"[{\ "product_id\ ":\ "2345\ ",\ "price\ ":{\ "currency\ ":\ "USD\ ",\ "amount\ ":\ "140.00\ ",\ "offset\ ":100},\ "quantity\ ":1}]"} |  |  |

(Note: I needed to include a space after the backslashes in the above table so that they would show up in the github generated markdown table -- my actual table does not include those spaces between the backslash and the quote character)

I am doing a sql query in Hive to get the 'currency' field.

Currently I can run

```
SELECT
    id,
    JSON_EXTRACT(obj, '$.products[0].price.currency')
FROM my_table
```

Which will give me the correct output for the first row, but gives me a NULL in the second row

| id | obj |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "USD" |
| 2 | NULL |

What is the best way to get currency field from the second row? Is there a way to clean up the field and remove the backslashes before trying to JSON_EXTRACT the relevant data?
I could use REPLACE to swap the '\ ' for '', but is that the most efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `\"` with `"` using `regexp_replace` like this:

```
regexp_replace(obj,'\\\\"','"')
```